# Query for many to many relationship database table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, performance, database-performance

I have list of data and a table like below.
**Data** : {ABC111,ABC112,ABC113,111111,111112,111113}
**Table**:

> ```
> Column 1 Column 2
> ABC111   ABC115
> ABC115   111333
> 111111   ABC112
> 111111   111112
> ABC123   111113
> 111113   ABC113
> ```

My result should be like below
**Result** : {ABC115,111333,111113,ABC113,ABC123,ABC112,111112}

**Explanation**:
*Data* - ABC111 is associated to ABC115 which is also associated to 111333. Hence the *result* is ABC115,111333.
Similarly, ABC113 is associated to 111113 which is also associated to ABC123. *Result* = 111113,ABC123.

Is it possible to implement the above using a query. Looking for Prepared statement to which I will pass the Data that I mentioned above.

Comment: `mysql` or `oracle`?

Comment: looking for mysql prepared statement

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Roopashree Is the order of result important here or they can be in any order

Comment: Order doesn't matter. @India.Rocket

Comment: then check my query. I have answered

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
/*CREATING RECORDS FOR THE MAIN TABLE*/

CREATE TABLE TABLES(Column1 text, Column2 text);

INSERT INTO TABLES VALUES('ABC111','ABC115');
INSERT INTO TABLES VALUES('ABC115','111333');
INSERT INTO TABLES VALUES('111111','ABC112');
INSERT INTO TABLES VALUES('111111','111112');
INSERT INTO TABLES VALUES('ABC123','111113');
INSERT INTO TABLES VALUES('111113','ABC113');
COMMIT;


/*CREATE LIST TO BE SUPPLIED*/

CREATE TABLE LIST(Column1 text);

INSERT INTO LIST VALUES('ABC111');
INSERT INTO LIST VALUES('ABC112');
INSERT INTO LIST VALUES('ABC113');
INSERT INTO LIST VALUES('111111');
INSERT INTO LIST VALUES('111112');
INSERT INTO LIST VALUES('111113');
COMMIT;


/*CODE TO GET THE RESULT*/

SELECT CONCAT('{',GROUP_CONCAT(RESULT),'}') AS RESULT FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1 AS RESULT FROM
  (
            Select a.column2 as column1,b.column2
            from
            (
            Select * from
            tables 
            where column1 in (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM LIST)
            ) a
            inner join
            tables b
            on a.column2=b.column1

            UNION ALL

            Select b.column2 as column1,b.column1 as Column2
            from
            (
            Select * from
            tables a
            where column2 in (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM LIST)
            ) a
            inner join
            tables b
            on a.column1=b.column2
) a

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN2 AS RESULT FROM 
(
            Select a.column2 as column1,b.column2
            from
            (
            Select * from
            tables 
            where column1 in (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM LIST)
            ) a
            inner join
            tables b
            on a.column2=b.column1

            UNION ALL

            Select b.column2 as column1,b.column1 as Column2
            from
            (
            Select * from
            tables a
            where column2 in (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM LIST)
            ) a
            inner join
            tables b
            on a.column1=b.column2
) a

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN2 AS RESULT FROM
(

        Select distinct a.Column1, a.column2  
        from
        (
        Select * from
        tables a
        where column2 in (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM LIST)
        ) a
        inner join
        (
        Select * from
        tables a
        where column2 in (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM LIST)
        ) b
        on a.column1=b.column1
        where a.column2 not in 
    (
    Select column1 from 
        (
            Select b.column2 as column1,b.column1 as Column2
            from
            (
            Select * from
            tables a
            where column2 in (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM LIST)
            ) a
            inner join
            tables b
            on a.column1=b.column2
         ) a
    )       
  ) a
) a;
```

Hope this helps:-)

Comment: That was really helpful @India.Rocket I hope you are using recursive query. I just want to confirm if this is an efficient way. Is there any other way of implementing it efficiently. Can we implement this using java and sql combined?

Comment: I don't know Java and I don't think it can be done using recursive query. I thought about it a lot. But if someone can answer it that way that will be great. Anyways a very nice question.